# LINQ vs Stored Procedures vs Inline Queries

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

We are a small team working on a very tight deadline to develop a large web application in .NET. We are using multiple databases (one per client) so our requirements are slightly different than most applications. The databases will only be used for this particular application so it doesn't matter if they are tightly coupled with the application. The main deciding factors are speed of development, long-term maintainability, and security. There are 3 options we are considering:

**Option 1 -  LINQ to SQL**

None of us have any experience with LINQ, but we have been researching it and it seems like a good option and not too difficult to learn. Worth the risk of learning a new method on a tight deadline?

**Option 2 - Stored Procedures**

Seems like it could be a nightmare to maintain with the multiple database setup (or would it?) and it may slow down development to work in another environment as we don't have a dedicated database developer. Basic CRUD queries would be generated by code generator which is an advantage.

**Option 3 - Inline Queries**

This method would be the fastest to develop but I know people are generally against hard-coded queries nowadays and I fear we may suffer in the long term with maintainability issues. Basic CRUD queries would be generated by code generator.

Please let me know if there are any factors we are missing. What solution seems the most appropriate for this project?

Comment: how large is 'large' and how tight is 'tight'?  I ask because learning Linq2SQL isn't hard and will likely improve your time to finish if you are talking about more than a week or two.  But if large is 'large enough' you will likely run into a weakness or two in it and need something else anyways.

Comment: Deadline is 3-4 months and the project isn't incredibly complicated or massive, just large in comparison to our past projects and size of our team. There will probably be 30-40 tables.

Comment: While it's very hard to say since I have no idea about your domain, but with NoSQL you could most likely model your entire data store in probably 10~15 aggregate roots. Possibly even less. The current application I'm building with RavenDB we have 1 primary aggregate root, and 2 ancillary ones that are more for historical purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a tight deadline don't try something new. Ask the devs to study Entity Framework at home and in their spare time and try it in next project. Meanwhile do what you know best and have used in past successfully.

Inline queries are not bad if they are decoupled in a DAL assembly.

Comment: Agree with this, and I recommend taking a look at Dapper, which allows you to write inline queries with less ado.net boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Since @Hasan Khan covered the primary answers regarding SQL. I'm going to throw out a somewhat different answer. Another option is to consider usage of RavenDB, a NoSQL db. It has the concept of Tenant databases inherently baked into it. Which from your requirements it sounds like this is the intended goal.